# ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2 Saml2LogoutRequest - NameQualifier and SPNameQualifier come up empty

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I'm using ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2 to process Logout Request.
With this bit of code I'm expecting to retrieve these three NameId elements from the incoming request:

```
Saml2LogoutRequest logoutRequest = new Saml2LogoutRequest(config);
var binding = new Saml2PostBinding();
binding.ReadSamlRequest(Request.ToGenericHttpRequest(), logoutRequest);

string spNameQualifier = logoutRequest .NameId.SPNameQualifier;
string nameQualifier = logoutRequest .NameId.NameQualifier;
string nameIdValue = logoutRequest .NameId.Value;
```

I'm struggling to figure out why I'm getting empty **spNameQualifier** and **nameQualifier** while **nameIdValue** and **Format** contain the correct value.

[screenshot from debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNisN.png)

This is how the request looks like and I guess that all the data should be coming from the saml2:NameID element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<saml2p:LogoutRequest Destination="{value}" ID="{value}" IssueInstant="{value}" NotOnOrAfter="{value}" Version="2.0" xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">{value}</saml2:Issuer>
    <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
            <ds:Reference URI="{value}">
                <ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                </ds:Transforms>
                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                <ds:DigestValue>{value}</ds:DigestValue>
            </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>
{value}
</ds:SignatureValue>
    </ds:Signature>
    <saml2:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient" NameQualifier="{expectedNameQualifier}" SPNameQualifier="{expectedSPNameQualifier}" xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">{expectedAndRecievedValue}</saml2:NameID>
    <saml2p:SessionIndex>{value}</saml2p:SessionIndex>
</saml2p:LogoutRequest>
```

What am I missing and why won't the two properties parse properly?

With ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2 I'm trying to get data from the Logout Request to do some manual handling. I'm getting empty NameId elements: **spNameQualifier** and **nameQualifier** while **nameIdValue** and **Format** contain the correct value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that the code in ITfoxtec Identity Saml2 only reads the NameID [without](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/src/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/Request/Saml2LogoutRequest.cs#L53) or [with a format](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/src/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/Request/Saml2LogoutRequest.cs#L57). The SPNameQualifier and NameQualifier properties is not read.

Feel free to make a pull request to add in code to read the SPNameQualifier and NameQualifier properties and I'll release the functionality.
The git repository is https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2

*** EDITED ***

ITfoxtec Identity Saml2 has support for SPNameQualifier and NameQualifier in version [4.10.9-beta1](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/releases/tag/4.10.9-beta1).

Comment: Thank's, Andreas. Will look into it. :-)
If anyone else has the same problem before it happens - as a workaround I'm parsing the XML doc manually to get these data.